# How to get a Binding to other Class than ItemsSource from within ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

I have a class ShapeGrid which contains basic information such as size and contains a list of Shape. While printing out every object in Shapes how do I get ShapeSize property from ShapeGrid?

```
public class ShapeGrid
{
    public List<Shape> Shapes { get; set; }
    public int GridSize { get; private set; }
    public double ShapeSize { get; private set; }
}

public class Shape
{
    public Brush Color { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

While using ContentControl I can get the container class but am unable to view list of all shapes without writing them out one by one.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ShapeGrid}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2">
     <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Shapes[0].Color}" Height="{Binding ShapeSize}" Width="{Binding ShapeSize}" />
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

While using ItemsSource I won't be able to access the container values.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ShapeGrid.Shapes}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Color}" Height="20" Width="20" />
                //this is what I want to
                //<Rectangle Fill="{Binding Color}" Height="{Binding ShapeGrid.ShapeSize}" Width="{Binding ShapeGrid.ShapeSize}" />
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I need the ShapeSize from ShapeGrid and the Color from Shape, both in the Rectangle tag. Is there a way to do this?

*Edit: I could put the ShapeSize property in each individual Shape but imagine if it was any kind of external value like windowSize etc.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is the purpose of using a ContentControl without the ContentPresenter in the template (which allows you to place your Rectangle as the content rather than the template, and also allow you to use the bindings directly.

However assuming that this is intentional:
The issue is that you lose the context inside the template.
What you could use is a binding proxy, which will allow you to bind to objects from the parent in the template.
You can find an example implementation of it here: 
https://thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/

then you could do something like this (not tested):

```
<ContentControl x:name="MyContentControl" Content="{Binding ShapeGrid}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2">
 <ContentControl.Resources>
       <local:BindingProxy x:Key="shapeProxy" Data="{Binding ShapeGrid}" />
 </ContentControl.Resources>
 <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <WrapPanel>
            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Shapes[0].Color}" Height="{StaticResource  shapeProxy, Path=Data.ShapeSize}" Width="{StaticResource  shapeProxy, Path=Data.ShapeSize}" />
        </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed but instead as an ItemsControl since Shapes is a list, but the concept still works the same. Thanks :)